# Operators that improve strong convergence to norm convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

It is well known that if $K$ is a compact operator on a Hilbert space, and $T_n$ is a sequence of operators converging strongly to $T$, then $K T_n$ converges in norm to $K T$.

Question : are there other operators $K$ that also satisfy this property, but are not compact ?

Thanks

Comment: On a separable Hilbert space, $K$ is necessarily compact: given an ONB $(x_n)_n$, define $T_n x =\sum_{\ell=1}^n x_\ell \langle x,x_\ell \rangle$. Then $T_n$ converges strongly to the identity. By assumption, $K T_n \to K$ in norm topology. But $T K_n$ has finite rank (why?). As a limit of finite rank operators in the norm topology, $K$ must be constant. I am not sure about non-separable Hilbert spaces, though.

Comment: Oh...right thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement made by the OP that:

> It is well known that if $K$ is a compact operator on a Hilbert space,
> and $T_n$ is a sequence of operators converging strongly to $T$, then
> $K T_n$ converges in norm to $K T$.

is being questioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3935048/does-left-multiplication-by-compact-operators-turn-strong-convergence-into-norm).  Nevertheless I have no qualms with the corresponding statement in which $K T_n$ and $KT$ are replaced by
$T_nK$ and $TK$, so I will read the present question with that modification.

My goal it thus to give a negative answer, namely to prove that if an operator $K$ has this property, then it is
necessarily compact.

$\newcommand{\one}{{\mathbb 1}}$
**Lemma**.  Let  $T$ be a bounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$  which is not compact.  Then there exists an
infinite dimensional subspace $K\subseteq H$, and a constant $c>0$, such that
$$
  \|T\xi \|\geq  c\|\xi \|, \quad \forall \xi \in  K.
  \tag 1
  $$

*Proof*. Let us assume first that $T$ is positive semi-definite.
For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let $\one_n$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[1/n, +\infty )$, and observe that
$$
  x\one_n(x) \ {\buildrel {n\to\infty}\over\longrightarrow}\ x,
  $$
uniformly on $[0,+\infty )$, so   it follows that
$$
  T\one_n(T) \to T,
  \tag  2
  $$
in norm.
Notice that the   $\one_n(T)$ form an increasing family of self-adjoint projections and we claim that they cannot
all  have finite rank.  This is because otherwise   $T\one_n(T)$ would also be finite rank, and then $T$ would be compact
by   (2).

Choosing any $n$ such that $\one_n(T)$ has infinite rank, let $K$ be the range of $\one_n(T)$, hence an infinite
dimensional subspace.   The proof will then be concluded once we show that
$$
  \|T\xi \|\geq  \frac1n   \|\xi \|, \quad \forall \xi \in  K.
  \tag 3
  $$
To prove this
notice that
$$
  x\one_n(x) \geq  \frac{\one_n(x)}n, \quad \forall x \in  [0,+\infty ),
  $$
so we have that
$$
  nT\one_n(T) \geq  \one_n(T).
  $$
For all $\xi $ in $K$,  a.k.a. the range of $\one_n(T)$, we then have that
$$
  \|\xi \|^2 =
  \langle \xi , \xi \rangle  =
  \langle \one_n(T)\xi , \xi \rangle  \leq
  n\langle T\one_n(T)\xi ,\xi \rangle  =
  n\langle T\xi ,\xi \rangle  \leq
  n\|T\xi \|\|\xi \|,
  $$
from where (3) follows.

Returning to the general case, in which $T$ is only assumed to be a bounded operator, let
$|T|=(T^*T)^{1/2}$, which is positive semi-definite.   Observing that
$$
  \|T(\xi)\| = \|\, |T|(\xi) \, \|,\quad \forall \xi \in  H,
  $$
we  see that any pair $(K,c)$ that works for $|T|$, also works for $T$.
QED

**Theorem**.    Let $T$ be an operator on a Hilbert space $H$ such that, whenever $\{S_n\}_n$ is a
sequence of bounded operators, strongly converging to zero, one has that $S_nT\to0$ in norm.  Then $T$ is compact.

*Proof*.  Assuming by contradiction that $T$ is not compact,  use the Lemma to find an infinite dimensional subspace $K\subseteq H$, and a
constant $c>0$,  such that  (1) holds.

Setting $L=T(K)$, is is easy to see that $T$ provides a bounded, linear, invertible map
$$
  \check T:K\to L,
  $$
with bounded inverse  and, in particular, that $L$ is a
closed  infinite dimensional subspace of $H$.

One may then easily  find a sequence of operators $\{S_n\}_n\subseteq B(L)$ which converges to zero
strongly, but not in norm.   Extending each $S_n$ to $H$ by setting it to be zero on $L^\perp$, it is clear that the
extended operators $\hat S_n$ also satisfy $\hat S_n\to0$ strongly, but not in norm.

By the assumption on $T$ we have that $\|\hat S_nT\|\to 0$, so
$$
  \|S_n\| =
  \|S_n\check T\check T^{-1}\|  \leq
  \|S_n\check T\| \|\check T^{-1}\| = $$$$ =
  \|\hat S_nT|_K\| \|\check T^{-1}\| \leq
  \|\hat S_nT\| \|\check T^{-1}\| \to 0
  $$
contradicting the choice of $S_n$.
QED

Comment: Very very nice! +1

Comment: Thanks!  Would you like to try a shot at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3935048/does-left-multiplication-by-compact-operators-turn-strong-convergence-into-norm ?

Comment: I see you have an answer deleted. Why is that? (Users with 10k+ rep can see deleted answers).

Comment: I didn't know people could find out when there are deleted answers, and I'd be curious to learn how.  Anyways, the reason is partly explained in PS(1) there.

Comment: I edited my above comment, but maybe you missed it. But I spoiled myself by seeing your answer. I think it is better to edit the answer and place it in a spoiler box. A shift operator gives surprisingly often good counterexamples!

Comment: Holy super users, Batman!  OK, I did as you said.  But I'm not going to undelete it yet since I don't want to dicourage answers.  Anyway, weren't you surprised by it?  @MathQED

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm a functional analysis newbie. For me it is obvious that if $T_i \to T$ strongly, then $T_iK \to TK$ in norm for the simple reason that we can approximate $K$ by finite rank operators which reduces the proof to showing that $T_i F \to TF$ in norm when $T_i F \to TF$ strongly and $F$ is a finite rank operator. The latter is easily seen, for example by taking an orthonormal basis for the image of the finite rank operator. But frankly, I don't see why any reason you would expect that $KT_i \to KT$ strongly implies $K T_i \to KT$ in norm?

Comment: You are totally correct.  The statement that $KT_i\to KT$ is just a common misconception, as you can see in the statement of this question.  Another indication that this is widespread is the comment by MaoWao, in which the questioning falls squarely outside the point by emphasizing the difference between nets and sequences.  It surprised me because I am (or at least am supposed to be) a professional functional analyst and I seem to have been under the same misconception until recently! @MathQED

Comment: This discussion reminds me of the highly interesting MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics